# "recipe commences before first target" error during "make" command while building Android

Tags: android, makefile, ubuntu-14.04

When I tried to run a build in Android-2.3.4_r1 on ubuntu-14, I get the following output:

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=2.3.4
TARGET_PRODUCT=generic
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_SIMULATOR=false
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=GRJ22
============================================
build/core/prebuilt.mk:101: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.
```

So, the line 101 in the file refer to the following :-

```
 99 ifneq ($(prebuilt_module_is_a_library),)
100  ifneq ($(LOCAL_IS_HOST_MODULE),)
101     $(transform-host-ranlib-copy-hack)
102  else
103     $(transform-ranlib-copy-hack)
104  endif
105 endif
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, I've manage to solve the problem by building it using Ubuntu 12.04 instead of using Ubuntu 14. I dont encounter the same error anymore.